# PHP/Laravel I can't seem to upload .GIF images

Tags: php, image, laravel, upload, gif

What happens is that when I upload regular images like .jpeg, .jpg, .png files, It all uploads and posts on my site like nothing is wrong. But as soon as I try to upload a .gif file. The site refreshes, empties out my input field, and then prompts out an error message saying that the field is required (Say's that when an input field is empty).

My method:

```
public function upload(Requests\CreatePostsRequest $request)
    {
        $target_dir = "uploads/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $findme   = ".";
        $pos = strpos($target_file, $findme);
        //dd($_POST);
        $imageFileType = strtolower(substr($target_file,$pos+1));
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
                //dd($check);
            if($check !== false) {
                echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
                $uploadOk = 1;
            } else {
                echo "File is not an image.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
        }
        $filecheck = 0;
        $orgFileName = $target_file;
        while (file_exists($target_file)) {
            $target_file = substr($orgFileName,0,$pos).$filecheck.substr($orgFileName,$pos);
            $filecheck++;

            $uploadOk = 1;
        }

        if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
            echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        } else if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] < 5000) {
            echo "Sorry, your file is too small.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
        && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
            echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
                echo $imageFileType;
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";

                        $post = new Posts($request->all());
                        $post->fileToUpload = $target_file;
                        Auth::user()->posts()->save($post);

                        //$request = Request::all();
                        //$post = new Posts();
                        //$post->title = $request['title'];
                        //$post->user_id = Auth::user()->posts();
                        //$post->src = $target_file;
                        //$post->save();
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
        return redirect('');
        echo $target_file;
    }
```

And here is my Form:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <ul class="alert alert-danger">
      @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
    @endif
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Create a Post</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            {!! Form::open(['url' => 'upload', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
                <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('title', 'Title: ') !!}
                {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="from-group">
                {!! Form::label('body', 'Select image to upload: ') !!}
                {!! Form::input('file', 'fileToUpload', null, ['class' => 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block', 'id' => 'fileToUpload']) !!}
                {!! Form::submit('Upload Image', ['class' => 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block', 'name' => 'submit', 'accept' => 'image/gif']) !!}
                </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

My model is correct and everything is fillable.

Comment: you never bother checking if the upload was successful. checking for non-zero bytes is **NOT** valid. there's a `['error']` paramter in $_FILES for a reason... and checking filename extensions is also not a proper way to test for images. `getimagesize` will TELL you what the type of the image is, regardless of what the file's name is.

Comment: Thanks, I've found my error, Turns out in my php.ini My upload_max_filesize was 2MB and I was attempting to upload a 5MB .gif.